# Negative left and right margin of .row class in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Just out of curiosity, why bootstrap uses `-15px` left and right `margin`s which going to cancel the `15px` left and right `padding` on  `.container` and `.container-fluid` classes.
Why set padding and then cancel it with a negative margin on the child?

Answer (score 2):

A negative margin on row avoids the blank space that would be left because of padding of first column. In its absence the whole layout will look a little indented.

Comment: But there is 15px padding on the container. Why is that? why not be like this instead:  .container { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }  .row {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }

Comment: The left and right padding in columns is present so that we have a gutter between columns, a separator. By the way Bootstrap provides a custom build option so that we can change these values based on requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As in [Official Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) said:

> **Rows** are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal `padding` (*called a gutter*) for controlling the space between them. This `padding` is then counteracted on the rows with negative `margins`. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.